# How to retrieve favorite videos with google api java client library?

Tags: youtube, google-api, gdata-api, gdata, google-api-java-client

I'm trying to retrieve the favorite videos of a youtube user with [google api java client library](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/). It's just a tweak of the [youtube-json-sample](http://samples.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/youtube-jsonc-sample/instructions.html?r=default). What I basically want to do is to print a list of the favorite videos of a user (specifically print title, updated, description etc). I do manage to get the list - but the problem is that everything (title, description etc) is null! This happens only with favorites - I tested it with search and most viewed queries and it worked. This strange behavior is only with favorites... Here is my code:

```
private  void run() throws IOException {
        YouTubeClient client = new YouTubeClient();
        showVideos(client);
      }

    private VideoFeed showVideos(YouTubeClient client) throws IOException {

        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        View.header(textView, "Get Videos");
        YouTubeUrl url = YouTubeUrl.forVideosFeed();
        // execute GData request for the feed
        VideoFeed feed = client.executeGetVideoFeed(url);
        View.display(textView, feed);
        return feed;
      }

public class YouTubeUrl extends GoogleUrl {

  /** Whether to pretty print HTTP requests and responses. */
  private static final boolean PRETTY_PRINT = true;

  static final String ROOT_URL = "https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api";



  YouTubeUrl(String encodedUrl) {
    super(encodedUrl);
    this.alt = "jsonc";
    this.prettyprint = PRETTY_PRINT;
  }

  private static YouTubeUrl root() {
    return new YouTubeUrl(ROOT_URL);
  }

  public static YouTubeUrl forVideosFeed() {
    YouTubeUrl result = root();

    result.getPathParts().add("users"); //the URL is http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/username/favorites?v=2
    result.getPathParts().add("liorash1"); //some user name
    result.getPathParts().add("favorites");

    return result;
  }
}

public class YouTubeClient {

  private final JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();

  private final HttpTransport transport = new NetHttpTransport();

  private final HttpRequestFactory requestFactory;

  public YouTubeClient() {
    final JsonCParser parser = new JsonCParser(jsonFactory);
    requestFactory = transport.createRequestFactory(new HttpRequestInitializer() {

      @Override
      public void initialize(HttpRequest request) {
        // headers
        GoogleHeaders headers = new GoogleHeaders();
        headers.setApplicationName("Google-YouTubeSample/1.0");
        headers.gdataVersion = "2";
        request.setHeaders(headers);
        request.addParser(parser);
      }
    });
  }

  public VideoFeed executeGetVideoFeed(YouTubeUrl url) throws IOException {
    return executeGetFeed(url, VideoFeed.class);
  }

  private <F extends Feed<? extends Item>> F executeGetFeed(YouTubeUrl url, Class<F> feedClass)
      throws IOException {
    HttpRequest request = requestFactory.buildGetRequest(url);
    return request.execute().parseAs(feedClass);
  }
}

public class Item {

  @Key
  String title;

  @Key
  DateTime updated;
}

public class Video extends Item {

  @Key
  String description;

  @Key
  List<String> tags = new ArrayList<String>();

  @Key
  Player player;
}
```

There are classes that I didn't put here so it won't be too messy. 
Anyway the output I get is:

```
============== Get Videos ==============

Showing first 6 of 8 videos: 

-----------------------------------------------
Title: null
Updated: null

-----------------------------------------------
Title: null
Updated: null

-----------------------------------------------
Title: null
Updated: null

-----------------------------------------------
Title: null
Updated: null

-----------------------------------------------
Title: null
Updated: null

-----------------------------------------------
Title: null
Updated: null
```

---

SOME UPDATES:

After some testing I found out that I can get every feed I tested (including the user's uploads) except the favorites feed. The problem is most likely is with the JsonCParser:

```
return request.execute().parseAs(feedClass);
```